# Is the word Nazi italicized in MLA?

Tags: loanwords, italics, mla

Recently my writing tutor told me any word in a foreign language should be italicized.

I was unsure if MLA was important to answer this question; just in case, I've included it in the title.

I'm writing an essay which will include the word Nazi. I understand the word Nazi is a German word but commonly used by people of all languages, should this word be italicized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both MLA style and my favorite, *The Chicago Manual of Style*, require that foreign words be italicized.  But Nazi has become thoroughly anglicized.  There is even an American Nazi Party (ANP).  However, "Nazi" stands for *Nationalsozialismus*.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just in case anyone has this question in the future, I also just found this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/fait-accompli-to-italicize-or-not-to-italicize?rq=1) which has a lot of background on my question as well.