# Past tense of “to lie” versus past tense of “to lay”

Tags: conjugation, lie-lay-lain-laid, mnemonic

This part I understand clearly:

```
present past    past participle
-------------------------------
lie     lay     lain    
lay     laid    laid
```

I already understand that and so am *not* asking how to conjugate these two different verbs: I **do** already know how to conjugate both of them. Rather, I just don’t know how to **remember** how to conjugate them so that this sticks in my brain.

Both Professor Malcolm Gibson's *[Wonderful World of Words](http://web.ku.edu/%7Eedit/lie.html)*
and Grammar Girl offer mnemonics for the present tense — so I again stress that I am *not* asking about that! However, **they offer nothing for the past tenses**. [Grammar Girl](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/lay-versus-lie?page=1) even confesses:

> I tried and tried to come up with a mnemonic for this, but I couldn’t do it. [. . .]   Practice will help, and truthfully, I still have to look them up every time I use them.

How can I come to grips with this confusing conjugation, in order to intuit or assimilate it as far as possible, and to help me remember?

---

#### Footnote

I was inspired to ask this by [Kosmonaut’s laconic remark:](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3460/50720)

> Most people don’t even know the correct **paradigm** for conjugating these verbs [read: *lie* and *lay*].

Is there such a “paradigm”?

Comment: *To lie* belongs to a group of verbs whose past tense forms a causative present tense. In other words, *to lay* means *to cause to lie*, just as *to fell* means *to cause to fall*. There are also some less obvious ones, altered by the course of time, such as *to set* meaning *to cause to sit*.

Comment: *I heed the Etymological Fallacy* ?? Whazat?

Comment: @BlessedGeek By 'heed', I mean its equivalent 'pay heed to' ; I'm just trying to minimise the number of words.

Comment: Minimizing word number can obfuscate. Also, the formatting needs help.

Comment: songs are good mnemonics [**Lay, Lady, Lay**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6ODMKSWzT4) By Bob Dylan. *Lay across my big brass bed. Lay, lady, lay, lay across my big brass bed....Lay, lady, lay, lay across my big brass bed.
Stay, lady, stay, stay while the night is still ahead*

Comment: Still, @Mari-LouA, using that song as mnemonic would steer one dead wrong on the transitive/intransitive distinction between *lay* and *lie,* and also it contributes nothing to the requested mnemonic for past tenses. I remember one song on an old folk album with the line "they laid Jesus Christ in his grave," but that may well be too obscure to have any mnemonic value for most people.

Comment: He laid down his blade, and since has lain among the slain. That's two out of four, at least.

Comment: @BrianDonovan thank you for telling me, I honestly hadn't realized. :)

Comment: If you play it, it is played; if you lay it, it is laid. But if you lie, it is plain, once you've done so, you have lain.

Comment: lie - lay - lain; lay - laid - laid, and lie - lied - lied:

Answer (score 2):

## Mnemonic: “Use a *d* when there is a *d*irect object”

The **paradigm** is the fixed-format part which you say you are perfectly clear on already:

| present tense | past tense | past participle |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lie | lay | lain |
| lay | laid | laid |

You say you know that and that you are not asking about that.  Fine: that solves the paradigm question, since you already know it.

As for actually remembering which is which, which I presume to be your **real** question, you need an *aide-mémoire*. Now, it is easier to construct a mnemonic for past participles than for simple pasts, but this will suffice because it leads to the right answer for both:

- Use the *n* in *recli**n**e* to match up with the same letter in *lai**n***.
- Use the *d* in ***d**irect object* to match up with the same letter in *lai**d***.  
  NB: This one also works for the past tense.

Therefore, the key concept for the memory-aid is that **d**irect object begins with the letter *d*, and so too do the past and past participle of *to lay* both end with that same letter.

Here’s your distilled memory-aid:

1. If there is a **d**irect object, use a *d* in the past and past participle — so *lay, laid, laid*.
2. If there is no **d**irect object, **don’t** use a *d* in the past or past participle — so *lie, lay, lain*.

To distill it even further, your mnemonic for remembering the paradigm is therefore “*d* for **d**irect object”.

---

As far as what is meant is concerned, no matter which verb is called (or shanghaied)  into service, the transitive use with a **d**irect object always means *to place something **d**own* while the intransitive one without an object always means *to rest, recli**n**e, remai**n***.

In other words, while you can lay things, things themselves simply lie there and do **n**othing.

To illustrate with a more Latinate example of combined forms used as participial adjectives that you might better connect with, *underlying* means subjacent (so resting beneath) while *overlaid* means superimposed (so placed on top of something else).

Comment: Thank you. Please don't mind the rollback; I want to generalise the question title; I still wish to make sense of these confusing conjugations if possible, and not only succumb to a mnemonic.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know whether this will help you but for Germans the  English forms are not so difficult. Compare:

E lie ------lay --- lain

G liegen lag gelegen (irregular verb type)

E lay ----laid --laid

G legen legte gelegt (regular verb type)

If it doesn't help you have to invent your own aid for remembering these forms.

Another memory aid.

1 lay was a regular verb: lay layed layed.

In the middle of a word y becomes i, so you get lay laied layed.
Drop e of ed as this e is no great use.

2 Now if this memory aid helps and you know that the second verb is
lie you have to remember that the second form is like the first form of verb 1. So you get

lie lay

As this verb was irregular the third form has -en. You get layen.
Change y into i and drop e as in the forms of verb 1. This way you get

lie lay lain

Comment: It's too convoluted, and recommending someone whose native language isn't German to use the first method is not the easiest solution. (You need to place key words in *italics*, to help the reader)

Comment: @Mari-LouA You’re absolutely right! My suggestion is in order to improve the reception of his answers here, for his next dozen postings to ***English* Language & Usage* this poster should endeavour never to mention the German language nor use any German words in those answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That’s why I said for the next dozen postings. Then he is allowed to revert to his old Teutonic self. :)

Comment: Oops, my bad, twelve sounds like a reasonable number...

Comment: In German, _liegen_ used to be ambiguous, as _lie_ is in English. But a dialectal form _lügen_ was substituted for the 'falsehood' sense of _liegen_, and now it's unambiguous in modern German. And of course, the full conjugation available in German makes the intransitive and the transitive causative forms immediately recognizable. In English the distinction is not apparent. Here's [a diagram showing why there's a problem](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/threekindsofword.pdf).