# Independance or Independence?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, orthography

What other words are like "independence" in British English where you replace the 'a' with an 'e'?

Comment: You mean when going from French to English? "Independence" is correctly spelled with an "e" in English.

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier and faster to check an online dictionary than to ask here?

Comment: No, I was just wondering if there were different words that were like this in such a situation.

Comment: Another American chiming in that "independance" is just as incorrect on this side of the pond as it is in England.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I reject your premise that "independance" is the American spelling; it's the French one. Both in British and in American English, "independence" is spelled with an "e". (There's even a [federal holiday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_Day_%28United_States%29).)

Comment: You're fighting a losing battle. I refer you to this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/descriptivism-and-widespread-misspelling

Comment: Not fighting any battles here, simply answering the question. The suffix "-ance" was [not invented in the US](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ance).

Answer (score 8):

Other words:

- [definately](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definately)
- persistance
- compatability
- dependant (depending on context)
- existance
- recommandation
- extant (depending on context)
- tendancy
- avarage
- deterrant
- occurance
- referance
- elimanate
- accessability
- efficiant
- simplar
- promenant
- privilage
- inadvertantly
- turbulance

They are **all** misspellings (some more common than others), just as *independance* is. [Source](http://www.irosetta.com/questions/vowel-substitutions).