# When do you use “learnt” and when “learned”?

Tags: american-english, orthography, british-english, past-tense, ed-vs-t

Is *learnt* UK English and *learned* US? Is it that simple?

I’m used to using *learnt*, but my US spellchecker says it is wrong.

Comment: Ever since I was a child, I always spelt it *learnt, dreamt, leapt* etc. I failed many English tests due to these spelling errors. It just doesn't look or feel right when I spell or say *learned, dreamed, leaped* etc. Maybe I'm stuck in a past life in 1810.

Comment: It mainly depends on what you learnt as a kid.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Merriam-Webster [marks](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/learnt) *learnt* as "chiefly British", and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/learnt) as "UK", adding that *learned* is the "Standard US English spelling". Quoting a linguist's comment from [elsewhere](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/),

> [[The Corpus of Historical American English] shows](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/?c=coha&q=6611030) that *learned* has always been more common than *learnt* in American English. At least, since 1810.

So it's not like *learnt* is completely unheard of in Americal English, but *learned* has always been more popular, and according to the COHA timetable, the usage of *learnt* has been on a more or less steady decline since 1820:

[image]

<sub>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words.)</sub>

Nowadays, according to the Corpus of Contemporary American English, *learnt* is most popular in the  context of fiction and academic publications, and least popular in newspapers:

```
           learned   learnt     RATIO

SPOKEN        9370       18     520.6
FICTION       9624       88     109.4
MAGAZINE     11924       18     662.4
NEWSPAPER     9224        6    1537.3
ACADEMIC      8921       96      92.9
```

What's more, even the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has more cites for *learned* than for *learnt*. The stats look as follows:

```
           learned   learnt     RATIO

SPOKEN         161      291       0.6
FICTION       1066      409       2.6
MAGAZINE       341      171       2.0
NEWSPAPER      459      151       3.0
NON-ACADEMIC   778      321       2.4
ACADEMIC       837      273       1.6
MISC          1588      537       3.0
```

It is worth noting that Merriam-Webster, Wiktionary, the American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, and Collins English Dictionary all list *learned* as both a verb form and an adjective, but *learnt* only as a verb form.

Lastly, here's a related question: [Dreamed vs. Dreamt, Leaped vs. Leapt, Lighted vs. Lit](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/).

Comment: wow, detailed answer, thanks! How *did* you do all that research? Great!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks. I _learned_ lots from this post!

Comment: I thought it best to point out that the quote you posted, is no longer available on the link. Maybe it was on a different question or the original comment was deleted.

Answer (score 17):

In American English, "learned" is the usual spelling; "learnt" is too rare.

In British English, both "learned" and "learnt" exist for the verb, but the adjective (as in "the learned professor") is always "learned". (Sometimes, especially archaically, "learnèd".)

Comment: would it be a grave on learnèd rather than an acute?

Comment: @John: You're right, "learnéd" should have been "learnèd". Fixed now.

Comment: The accent is used in American publications too, to emphasize that it's the adjective: "Sanskrit was usually both a learned and learnèd language", etc.

Answer (score 1):

> > [image: learned vs learnt]
>
> [[**Learniv**](https://en.learniv.com/info/en/irregular-verbs/learnt-or-learned-what-is-correct-and-how-to-use-it/)]

This verb has both an irregular and regular form. You can use both and both are correct. Speakers in North America and Canada use learned while the rest of the English-speaking world seems to prefer learnt.

Learned (but not learnt) is also an adjective. When said of a person, it means ‘ having a lot of knowledge because you have studied and read a lot`.

It can also be used of objects, meaning ‘showing, requiring, or characterized by learning’.

Example: She is a ‘very learned’ woman.”

But which is the most used one? Let´s look at Google Ngram Viewer tool which displays a graph showing how phrases have occurred in a corpus of books over the years.

> > [image: Google Ngram results for 'learnt' and 'learned']

Learned is more used, but bear in your mind that „learned“ is also an adjective, so comparing with a verb is not representative.

Source: [[**Learniv**](https://en.learniv.com/info/en/irregular-verbs/learnt-or-learned-what-is-correct-and-how-to-use-it/)]