# When would one use "burnt" and when would "burned" be more appropriate?

Tags: differences, adjectives, conjugation, transatlantic-differences, ed-vs-t

More out of curiosity than anything, when would one use "burnt" and when would "burned" be appropriate? For example,

> This coffee tastes burnt.
>
> This coffee tastes burned.

or

> They burnt the coffee again.
>
> They burned the coffee again.

Does it make a difference? I know when I speak either phrase they sound almost indistinguishable (my "t"s do not always sound sharp and come across like "d"s at times); can they be used interchangeably?

[ As an aside, the problem with the coffee at the local Dunkin Donuts is what prompted the whole curiosity about this :) ]

Comment: I'd say "burnt toast", but "they burned the toast". FWIW, I've never encountered "burned" as an adjective, or "burnt" as a verb.

Comment: It seems the same question is being asked repeatedly on this site in many variants: [*learnt* vs *learned*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/when-do-you-use-learnt-and-when-learned), [*spelt* vs *spelled*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/spelt-and-spelled), and [*Dreamed vs. Dreamt, Leaped vs. Leapt, Lighted vs. Lit*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/dreamed-vs-dreamt-leaped-vs-leapt-lighted-vs-lit).

Comment: @J.M. Nor have I; "burnt" is the adj., and "burned" is the past tense of the verb "burn", but as I mentioned, they sound so similar. Could it be that they have been used in the wrong context, and so much so that it has become accepted in common conversation?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but it seems to me as if burned is a past tense verb, while burnt is an adjective. At least, it sounds better that way to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are both used as the past tense of *[burn](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burned)*.

In American English, *burned* is used much more frequently than *burnt*. In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), a search for *burned* returns more than 5 times more results than a search for *burnt* (11558 for *burned* vs. 2005 for *burnt*).  Note that in combination with certain nouns, *burnt* is actually what is in general used: "burnt ivory", "burnt cobalt", "burnt orange", "burnt yellow", "burn toast", "burnt smell", etc.

[image]
(For complete table use the compare tool between burned and burnt in the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).)

In British English, hovewer, they seem to be used with more similar frequency. In the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/), a search for *burned* returns 1435 results and a search for *burnt* returns 1252 results. Unlike American English, there are many occurrences of *burnt* as a verb too (e.g. "And I burnt them").

Comment: Your search does not distinguish between the verb and the adjective, right? So it's not much help in deciding which one is the more common adjective (or verb).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - that's correct, good point. I've updated my answer to show what words appear more often next to burned and burnt. Notice that as an adjective, burnt seems to be used more often.

Comment: In Australian English burnt is almost always the past tense and adjective. Some people might write it as burned, however, due to the final /t/ being realised as a glottal stop and people believing it to be a 'lazy d'. However I can assure you this is an underlying /t/.

Answer (score 2):

The simple past and past participle of *burn* is either *burned* or *burnt*.

In addition, *burnt* also functions as an adjective to describe something as being *damaged, injured, or made black from burning*, a meaning slightly different from it being used as a participial adjective.

Comment: but you can also say "the burned paper"

Comment: You can use past-tense regular verbs ("-ed" construction) to form adjectives in any case. "This is hallowed ground." "You're looking at manipulated data." "My car has heated seats." There is nothing wrong with saying "burned toast" even though it may be more common to say "burnt toast" where you live.

Comment: I wonder if the inevitability of "burnt toast" (in whichever variety/context Jasper was referring to) has something to do with the sound: "burnt toast" has two unvoiced consonants adjacent and seem easier to say.

Answer (score 2):

Burnt toast is easier to say than 'burned toast'. And some things said simply become the more commonly accepted way to say it and I think that's the case with 'burnt toast'.

There is also a shadow of some mountain regions of the South, of dialects of British English, of 'folk speech' in the word 'burnt' and others like it. My father in everyday discourse would say burned, dreamed, spelled but when with his brothers and mountain-raised Scot-Irish father would only say 'burnt, dreamt, and spelt as in 'Remember when Jim took the prize because he spelt so well?"

Comment: By "the South", do you mean the Southern United States? Or South England? (Or even the South of the British Isles, presumably England?) Or South of some other country altogether? It's confusing especially since you mention Scot-Irish… please don't make assumptions, and specify what dialect your answer applies to. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR it's a bit less confusing when they say "Scot-Irish", if you know that that's an American English term for Americans of Ulster-Scots descent.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the situation being described. If I came across something which had been subject to a burning I would say that it was burnt, where "burnt" describes the state of something which had been burned, but if I witnessed the burning I would say that I saw it being burned.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELU. Please support your answers with sources. They make your answers stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise it's only an opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.