# Difference between "burnt" and "burned"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

According to most dictionaries, both the words *burnt* and *burned* are past tenses of *burn*.

What is the difference between the two and can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When would one use "burnt" and when would "burned" be more appropriate?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6716/when-would-one-use-burnt-and-when-would-burned-be-more-appropriate)

Comment: Partly is has to do with active/passive/transitive/intransitive.