# "Lept" vs. "leapt" vs. "leaped"

Tags: differences, tenses, past-tense, simple-past, ed-vs-t

[After reading this discussion](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/forum/showthread.php?98-Leapt-Lept-Leaped), I'd like to know what example sentences distinguish the meaning of the words *lept*, *leapt*, and *leaped* from each other?

Comment: Lept is archaic and not used nowadays. Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/why-do-some-words-have-two-past-tense-forms-e-g-dreamed-vs-dreamt | http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/when-do-you-use-learnt-and-when-learned

Comment: @coleopterist *Lept* hasn’t been used since the 16th century, because the modern spelling is *leapt*.

Comment: Just to check, all three are pronounced the same, right?

Comment: @Mitch I don’t think so.  I think if you pronounce it `/lɛpt/`, then you spell it *leapt*, and if you pronounce it `/li:pt/`, then you spell it *leaped*.  I don’t know of any words that end in *‑eaped* but are pronounced `/ɛpt/`.  *lept* is the old spelling of *leapt*, while *leaped* is the result of people reanalysing *to leap* as a regular verb.  No, they don’t sound alike.

Comment: I just feel like (in AmE at least) that the past tense of 'to leap' is pronounced  /lɛpt/ but still spelled 'leaped'. [Free Dictionary: leaped or leapt (lɛpt, li:pt), leap·ing, leaps](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/leaped). MW spells it both ways and pronounces it both ways too without choosing which gos with which.

Comment: They are using leapt as a spelling vocabulary word in my triplets 3rd grade American classroom. Both my husband and myself had thought the spelling was wrong and we made our daughter change it to lept, until we looked it up. Learn something new every day!

Comment: Lept is a more usable spelling, insofar as the pronunciation is concerned.  Leapt is an attempt to make the past tense of the verb more similar to the present, as in go and went.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link to the discussion in which the word or words is used is no longer valid. There is thus no context. The necessary context would have shown if the words represent the past participle or the simple past.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The past tense of *leap* is today rightly spelt *leapt* when pronounced with [the DRESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English) vowel rather than with [the FLEECE vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Wells_Standard_Lexical_Sets_for_English), so /lɛpt/ rhyming with *kept*.

In contrast, *lept* is an **obsolete** spelling of *leapt* seldom seen since the 1500s, back before the standardization of English spelling.

Consider:

- *bleed > bled*
- *breed > bred*
- *creep > crept*
- *dream > dreamt*
- *feed > fed*
- *feel > felt*
- *kneel > knelt*
- *lead > led*
- *lean > leant*
- *meet > met*
- *plead > pled*
- *sleep > slept*
- *speed > sped*
- *sweep > swept*
- *weep > wept*

As you see, the sound change is more consistent than the spelling, but *leapt* is not wholly without precedent in other forms even when spelt that way.

Comment: Best to note that some of these also have regular alternatives.

Comment: "Pled" is the past tense of plead only in legal proceedings; otherwise "pleaded" is standard. (She pleaded with the professor to change her grade, etc.) 
I had never seen "leant" in my life before reading this post and had to look it up to make sure it's even a word; it is, but it's outdated. "Leaned" is the modern form. 
"Dreamed" is at least as common as "dreamt", at least when referring to literal dreams that one has while asleep. "Dreamt" gets more play for poetic / metaphorical uses, although it is also somewhat popular in the UK for the literal meaning as well.

Comment: A lot of the 'older' forms are still in use in such as Northern Br Eng. Dreamt, leant, treat [pronounced tret] are all still common.

Comment: The spelling seems quite consistent to me: ⟨ee⟩ becomes ⟨e⟩ everywhere; ⟨ea⟩ remains ⟨ea⟩ if a past-tense marker ⟨t⟩ is added to form the past tense; otherwise it too becomes ⟨e⟩.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Has anyone ever told you that you have a promising career in computer programming awaiting you? :=}

Comment: @tchrist Only the kind of people who think any kind of programming, no matter how simple, is pure magic. :-p

Answer (score 8):

Almost ten years ago, I checked and recorded the relative popularity of *leaped* and *leapt* in Google results, because the following assertion in *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (1989) intrigued me:

> In American English, *leaped* and *leapt* seem to be used with about equal frequency.

Recognizing that *leapt* is somewhat more common in British (and much of British Commonwealth) English than in U.S. English, I decided to run Google searches for the two terms, reasoning that if *leaped* came out significantly ahead in undifferentiated results, it was probably considerably more popular than *leapt* in U.S. usage.

My first round of searches for *leaped* and *leapt* (undated, but probably in 2004 or 2005) generated 6.2 million matches for *leaped* and 4.7 million matches for *leapt*. A second run, on 11 August 2010, produced these unexpected numbers: 8.73 million for *leaped*, 8.53 million for *leapt*, and 401,000 for *lept*. Today (22 January 2013), I ran the searches again and got these numbers: 7.06 million for *leaped*, 10.5 million for *leapt*, and 1.11 million for *lept*.

With regard to absolute numbers, Google searches are utterly unreliable because they generate so many repetitious matches for the same content. But for indicating shifts in relative popularity, I think that they can be useful. And in this case, a rather impressive shift in such popularity is evident—away from *leaped* and toward *leapt*. The numbers also suggest that *lept* is very far from vanishing as a variant spelling, though Merriam-Webster Online as yet declines to accept it as one.

An Ngram Viewer search for *leaped*, *leapt*, and *lept* confirms my initial impression/assumption that *leaped* is more common in published print content than *leapt*—and indeed indicates that it has been consistently so for more than 200 years. However, the rise of *leapt* in Google results and the absence of copyediting in much published work these days suggest that *leapt* may soon vindicate *Webster's Dictionary of English Usage*'s prematurely enthusiastic assessment of its popularity in the United States.

---

**Followup (April 4, 2021)**

This was one of my first answers on English Language & Usage—and I didn't yet know how to reproduce Ngram charts in answers on this site. I also was unaware that Ngram lets users break out results for British English and American English. With this knowledge now in hand, I am belatedly revisiting this answer to provide the relevant Ngram results.

First, here is the Ngram chart for all published occurrences of *leaped* (blue line) versus *leapt* (red line) versus *lept* (green line) for the period 1750–2019:

[image]

Next, here is the Ngram chart for the frequencies of the same three words over the same period in books and periodicals from British publishers:

[image]

And finally, here is the Ngram chart for the frequencies of the same three words over the same period in books and periodicals from North American publishers:

[image]

The most striking thing in these results is the evidence they provide that *leaped* was significantly more common than *leaped* in British publications from 1750 until the early twentieth century (the crossover in British preferences from *leaped* to *leapt* technically occurred between 1916 and 1917, according to Ngram). What caused this change? Writing in 1926, Henry Fowler, *A Dictionary of Modern English Usage* attributes it to a tendency (which he commends) to match spelling to pronunciation:

> **-T & -ED.** Typical words are *bereaved* & *bereft*, *burned* & *burnt*, *dreamed* & *dreamt*, *kneeled* & *knelt*, *leaned* & *leant*, *leaped* & *leapt*, *learned* & *learnt*, *smelled* & *smelt*, *spelled* & *spelt*, *spilled* & *spilt*, *spoiled* & *spoilt*, *tossed* & *tost*.
>
> In the last of these the point is purely one of spelling, & the sound is the same either way ;  there are many other verbs of which that is true (*husht*, *kist*, *whipt*, *curst*, *cookt*, &c.), & individual writers make a practice of using the short form as a piece of spelling reform, as time-saver, or an eccentricity ; whichever the motive, the effect is with most words eccentric ; but *tost*, esp. in p. p. compounds such as *storm-tost*, is current, by the side of *tossed*.
>
> Of the rest the spelling may affect the sound in some, & does affect it in others. Thus, *burned* may be sounded with d, but perhaps most even of those who spell it so sound it with t, whereas *leaped* & *leapt* are pronounced by everyone with different vowels—lēpt & lĕpt. The advice here offered is to use the -t spelling in both classes, & that in the face of the surely surprising figures to be given below ; it will hardly be denied that most people say bernt & lĕpt, not bernd & lēpt, & conformity between the written & the spoken word is worth securing where, since both spellings are already in use, it costs nothing. At present, however, the -ed forms still prevail in print over those in -t in most of our list ; and it should be added that, if the past tense were distinguished from the p. p., the preponderance of -ed for it would be slightly greater. The figures are arrived at by counting the occurrences in all OED quotations of the 19th and 20th cc. ...

Fowler then goes on to note (among other comparisons) seven relevant OED matches for *leaped* and five for *leapt*.

Writing almost forty years later, Ernest Gowers, *A Dictionary of Modern English*, revised edition (1965) updates us on the progress of relevant British English spelling preferences:

> **-t and -ed** Some verbs that once had an alternative -t form for past tense and participle have now lost it, either wholly or to an extent that makes it archaic, e.g. *curst*, *dropt*, *husht*, *kist*, *stopt*, *tost*, and *whipt*. For many others  -t is now the only formation, e.g. *crept*, *dealt*, *felt*, *kept*, *left*, *meant*, *slept*, *swept*. Typical of the words that have preserved both alternatives are *bereave*, *burn*, *dream*, *kneel*, *lean*, *leap*, *learn*, *smell*, *spell*, *spill*, and *spoil*.
>
> In the first edition of this dictionary an attempt was made to assess the comparative popularity of the two endings when used in print by counting the number of times they occur in all OED quotations of the 19th and 20th cc. ...
>
> So far as we can accept thee figures as a guide, it would seem that  the -ed forms then still prevailed in print; ... But there has since been a movement (advocated in the original edition) towards -t. *Lean* is the only word in the first group [which includes *leap*] for which the C[oncise] O[xford] D[ictionary] still puts -ed before -t; for *kneel* it admits no alternative to *knelt*.

In the North American English, meanwhile, the -*ed* forms have long been viewed as preferable (or at least dominant). From Margaret Nicholson, *A Dictionary of American-English Usage* (1957), based on the first edition of Fowler:

> **-t & -ed.** ... In US the -*ed* ending is much more general, esp. in writing; in Brit., the -*t*.

Bryan Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003) has a somewhat surprising take on *leaped* versus *leapt*:

> **leapt; leaped.** Both are acceptable past-tense and past-participial forms for the verb leap. Because *leapt* is pronounced /lept/, the mistaken form *lept* is frequently encountered ...
>
> *Leapt*, which used to be the more common form, is steadily being displaced by *leaped*: in frequency of use, the two forms are neck-and-neck in modern print sources. Traditionalists prefer *leapt*.

The Ngram chart for American English shows something quite different from what Garner describes. Although it does show a considerable narrowing of the distance in frequency between the two forms from roughly 1900 until about 1975, that narrowing involves a reduction in the advantage of *leaped* over *leapt*—not the reverse. And since 1976, despite the fact that both forms have seen impressive increases in frequency of use, the difference between the two has remained remarkably steady.

One might also ask what tradition traditionalists are basing their preference for *leapt* on. As Fowler noted, and as the Ngram charts tend to confirm, traditional spelling in both Britain and the United States has generally favored *leaped* by a very substantial margin. It would perhaps be more accurate to say, as Fowler does, that spelling reformers who favor the pronunciation lĕpt over the pronunciation lēpt clearly prefer the spelling *leapt*.

Several cautions about the Ngram results may be in order. First, the fact that a book has a British or North American publisher doesn't mean that its spelling has been altered to suit the publisher's preferences. If the book is by a British author—especially if it is a scientific or literary work, it may retain the author's original British spelling choices, and likewise (in reverse) for a British publisher's version of a U.S. author's work.

Second, the "American English" evidently doesn't distinguish between U.S. and Canadian publishers, although U.S. and Canadian spelling preferences differ on a number of points, including (potentially) some difference in degree of preference for *leaped* versus *leapt*. Margery Fee & Janice McAlpine, *[Oxford] Guide to Canadian English Usage*, second edition (2007) note that Canadian usage on *-ed* versus *-t* verb endings aligns more closely with U.S. usage than with British usage on many words, although with some degrees of difference on others:

> **-t, -ed** *Leant*, *learnt*, *smelt*, *spelt*, *spilt*, and *spoilt* are chiefly British forms of the past tense and past participle forms. Canadians, like Americans, are far more likely to use the *-ed* forms of these verbs. However, Canadians do use *burnt*, *dreamt*, *knelt*, and *leapt* quite often.

From this account, it is hard to tell whether *leapt* is more common in Canadian usage than in U.S. usage—but it would be unreasonable to rule out that possibility.

And third, Ngram results are subject to various optical character recognition errors, including misreading the spelling of the word in the original text and misreading the publication date of the cited book or periodical. Consequently, the more precisely one attempts to assert the accuracy of the percentage data that provide the basis for the Ngram line graphs, the more dubious the legitimacy of one's assertions becomes.

Still, in broad outline, the lines plotted for *leaped* and *leapt* over the period from 1750 to 2019—and especially since 1800 or so, appear to provide a reasonably reliable picture of the relative frequency of the two spellings in books and periodicals published by British, American, and combined publishing houses.

Comment: As you say yourself, Google is notoriously unreliable. (And NGrams is not always much better.) You should really have a look at professionally compiled and maintained corpora, such as the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and the [British National Corpus](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/). For historical trends, there's the [Corpus of Historical American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coha/). You sound like the kind of person who will dig working with them. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I found this quote here by Pam Peters (The Cambridge Guide to English Usage), and she says:

> **leaped or leapt**: Both spellings are used in American and British English, but the relativities work in opposite directions. In the US
>   the more regular spelling **leaped** is commoner by a factor of 5:1,
>   according to CCAE¹ data. In British data from the BNC²,
>   **leapt** is ahead by similar ratio.

Based on this, I think that you can use 'leaped' or 'leapt'; both are acceptable past-tense and past-participle forms for the verb *leap*. As Bryan A. Garner says³: “Because *leapt* is pronounced /lept/, the mistaken form *lept* is frequently encountered.”

¹<sub>CCAE: The Cambridge International Corpus of American English</sub>

²<sub>BNC: British National Corpus</sub>

³<sub>A Dictionary of Modern American Usage</sub>