# Leaped or leapt, past and perfect tenses

Tags: word-usage, tenses

Here is my passage, more or less:

**Dick and Jane leapt from the boat into the icy waters of the North Pacific. Had they not leaped, they would not have been eaten by sharks as the rescue helicopter was just minutes away.**

Leaped or leapt?
Had leaped or had leapt?
Has leaped sounds better to me than has leapt, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *["Lept" vs. "leapt" vs. "leaped"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76167/lept-vs-leapt-vs-leaped)* Also see *[Why do some words have two past tense forms (e.g. “dreamed” vs. “dreamt”)?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502)*

Comment: Yes, covered well by the links mentioned above. You should feel free to choose subjectively. For me, "leaped" leads more fluidly to the action-packed remainder of the sentence, whereas "leapt" [preferred spelling] *sounds* more halting if you want to emphasize a sense of hesitation.

Comment: The oddity is that he used the irregular form in the active voice and the regular form in the passive voice.

Comment: Exactly. I'd like to leave this open for a bit if y'all don't mind.

Comment: @StuW If the related questions do not address your question, please edit to indicate what more you are looking for.