# Online rhyme dictionary/rhyming resource that lists rhymes by vowel sound (assonance)

Tags: internet, dictionaries, rhymes, vowels

Anyone know of an online rhyming dictionary or rhyme resource that lists rhymes by vowel sound (assonance)? RhymeZone.com doesn't have such an option.

Comment: ...and suddenly the word "rhyming" looks very strange to me :)

Comment: [Semantic satiation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/), eh?

Comment: Heh, didn't know there was a name for it. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: Do you mean by vowel sound only, disregarding the coda?

Comment: I believe so. All consonants should ideally be disregarded. For example, mix would rhyme with fifths, sixths, miss, fish, lips, and even words with non-s codas such as glyph, quid, flick, width, rib, silk, etc. The words with l-codas such as "silk" are a stretch as far as rhymes go, since the l-sound is softer than most other consonants, but an ideal assonance rhyming dictionary should leave it up to the user to decide whether or not to use such a rhyme.

Comment: This seems like it shouldn't be too hard to write a program for. However, the result set is going to be HUGE. If I find time, I may try to right up an example program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link that may help:

http://www.wikirhymer.com/

<strike>It's a little weird to use. You have to select a word from the dropdown list. As it says, you have to

". . . type a word into the Find Rhymes box. Select a word from the dropdown list and you will be whisked to the appropriate set of rhyming words including all near and 'pure' (also known as hard) rhymes."</strike>

They've made it much easier to use now. Just type a word in the Search box and you can look for its "pure", "end", "near" or "near end" rhyme.

Comment: That is indeed quite weird, but it works. Hope they update that functionality soon! Anyway, thanks a bunch for finding this. I may have actually used it before, but if so I probably just didn't remember or otherwise realize that it had the near rhymes feature.

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now returning 404

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Updated the link.. Unfortunately, the link will eventually get outdated. But since the OP asked for a link, there's really no getting around it:(

Comment: Sadly, WikiRhymer has gone commercial. They now charge $7 per year for a "Pro" membership and blocks unpaid users from accessing the complete list of near rhymes. Rhyme Desk mentioned below, while not as exhaustive as WikiRhymer, looks like an interesting alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.prime-rhyme.com. It might have the functionality you asked about if I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rhymedesk.com - search for near rhymes and organize results by "rhyme type" and you will get assonance as well as consonance rhymes.

Answer (score 0):

Www.rhymewave.com
I’m telling you here’s what your looking for
You’re welcome

Comment: doesn't seem to list rhymes by syllable