# What is a "thread of a bow" called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there an English word (a noun) that is an equivalent to the "thread/string of a bow" from a bow and arrow?

Comment: -1; This seems a little too easy to answer by simply looking it up.

Comment: Do you mean bow as in bow and arrow or as in the bow on top of a present?  Great, now I've typed bow too many times and it looks wrong.

Comment: @Kevin: [Semantic satiation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/), eh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bow string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowstring)?

Comment: You can even remove the space: _bowstring_ is a word.

Comment: @MrHen: check the link. Cerberus is covering all his bases.)))

Comment: @Reg: The comment wasn't directed at Cerberus but people browsing in the future.

Comment: +1 to the answer. @MrHen: [I agree](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0096800#m_en_gb0096800). I'd use it as one word.