# What to call a brief sentence that comes before/after the main clause with only a comma

Tags: punctuation, clauses

Here is my passage. I believe I'm doing it right, but I'm not sure why.

Does this have a specific name? It doesn't seem like an interjection to me, so I'm not sure why I'm so comfortable using a comma rather than a semicolon.

> "Do you come here often?"
>   "I guess I like the ambience, I don't know."

There are some other examples besides *"I don't know"*, but I'm blanking on them right now.

Edit: I thought of a couple more examples that are a little less obvious of a comma splice

**"Truth is, I really don't like Cheetos all that much."** I used to use a colon for "Truth is ..." but now I use a comma.

**"I know why you know why I know that, you know."** I have always used a comma for "you know" as an independent clause.

Comment: Does the question form of this fit your idea, *"You're going to make that pizza, are you?"*

Comment: Let me rephrase: interrogatives are different (as are commands and interjections; I'm talking about a traditional subject-verb-predicate sentence).

Comment: Possible duplicate of and certainly answered at [Is it grammatically correct to combine 2 phrases into 1 sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-combine-2-phrases-into-1-sentence). This is called by some a 'run-on sentence' (two main/independent clauses separated here by a mere comma: a comma splice). Its acceptability is discussed in the previous article. Nowadays, this particular example wouldn't cause many people as much concern as it would have thirty years ago.