# Does a period, semicolon, comma, or nothing go there?

Tags: commas, syntactic-analysis, semicolons, periods

Recently, I was being tongue in cheek when I wrote the following words:

- I'm quite dead, I assure you.

Someone felt inclined to correct my grammar and say that it was a comma splice.  They suggested that I should've written it one of the following ways:

- I'm quite dead.  I assure you.
- I'm quite dead; I assure you.

Their reasoning was that it's two main clauses not joined by a conjunction.  I see where they are coming from, but it also looked strange to me because what I meant was:

- I assure you (that) I'm quite dead.

I simply inverted it.  The "that" is implied.  Does inverting the sentence affect punctuation?  Where I might have put no punctuation otherwise, is punctuation now required?  If so, is a comma sufficient or is either a semicolon or period required?    Which would be the proper way to write such sentences?

A.  I'm quite dead I assure you.

B.  I'm quite dead, I assure you.

C.  I'm quite dead; I assure you.

D.  I'm quite dead.  I assure you.

Comment: In a nutshell, you were correct and they were wrong.  I'll have to let someone else get into the gory details, though.

Comment: Personally, I would use a colon or an mdash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Google search for "He's quite dead. I assure you." (which as expected shows more hits than the "I'm" version, if not many more) only gives examples of your versions B and A.

Comma splices are not wrong per se, as discussed in [this previous thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-combine-2-phrases-into-1-sentence/233604#233604). And I'd say that version B is the best here ('I assure you' is best not analysed as an independent clause anyway).

Version A 'reads' wrongly, to my ears: the natural pause isn't signalled.

Version C treats 'I assure you that', essentially, as an independent clause, and is clumsy at best.

Version D is fine if you want a more dramatic pause.

Version B treats 'I assure you' as a modality marker, a parenthetical, which is probably best set off by the comma.