# Don't worry, that's where I come in vs Don't worry; that's where I come in

Tags: commas, semicolons

I know the second one is correct: Don't worry; that's where I come in. As they are both independent clauses.

My question is: would it be *incorrect* to say: "Don't worry, that's where I come in"? Or is it one of those which is technically incorrect but generally accepted? As I feel like the second version is a bit too formal for general use.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the use of a semicolon in the sentence 'The south sided with the King; the north with the usurper.' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385648/is-the-use-of-a-semicolon-in-the-sentence-the-south-sided-with-the-king-the-no) Only a hyperprescriptivist would consider the comma splice unacceptable in this example. With no editors / professors that I must bow to, I'd choose the comma for little to no pause in a smooth delivery, and a dash for a dramatic pause. The semicolon (whilst not incorrect) looks a little ugly here.

Comment: This is something that would be **said**, not written -- unless one were reporting dialog, in which case punctuation would be up to the author and editor. In speech, of course, there's no punctuation.

Comment: to come in is short for: come in[to the picture], for example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be either, it just depends on what you're writing it for, if you're writing it for a college paper, or something really important, it's probably best to use the semicolon for that; but if you're just writing a story or something informal, then it's okay to use the comma.