# Comma vs semicolon for "This is not a war, it's a revolution."

Tags: grammar, commas, semicolons, independent-clauses

I understand that they are both independent clauses. Therefore, a semicolon should theoretically be used:

> This is not a war; it's a revolution.

However, I think it reads a little weird. And seeing as it's a very short sentence, would it be acceptable to say:

> This is not a war, it's a revolution.

Comment: 'Theoretically, meaning 'according to the _never join independent clauses with a comma_ prescription. Here, the comma is fine, probably the better choice. Read what Barbara Wallrafff says at the duplicate thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the use of a semicolon in the sentence 'The south sided with the King; the north with the usurper.' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385648/is-the-use-of-a-semicolon-in-the-sentence-the-south-sided-with-the-king-the-no)