# Punctuation: I miss them too, they’re adorable. or (too; they’re adorable.) or (too. They’re adorable.)

Tags: punctuation

What is the right punctuation for the last sentence?

There were two parks in my old neighborhood, where kids used to ride their bicycles. I miss the park kids too; they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too; they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too, they’re adorable.

I miss the park kids too. They’re adorable.​

Comment: If the parks no longer exist, then neither do the "park kids." In which case the auxiliary  verb should also be in the past: *They **were** adorable.*

Comment: Is this formal or informal writing? Semicolon is too much for a text message but fine in a book.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Let's say: they're grown-ups now.
This is a part of dictation passage for students to differentiate between there, their, and they're - where and were.

Comment: If they are grownups, they are no longer kids. Just saying.

Comment: @Mari-LouA So what's your choice for punctuation?

Comment: I would use semicolon or start a new sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the use of a semicolon in the sentence 'The south sided with the King; the north with the usurper.' correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385648/is-the-use-of-a-semicolon-in-the-sentence-the-south-sided-with-the-king-the-no) // Here, << I like the kids, they’re adorable. >> seems less in need of the traditionally mandatory semicolon (/ dash / ellipsis / period)  than << I miss the children who used to play in the park too, they were adorable. >>