# Another question regarding usage of comma vs. semicolon

Tags: punctuation

Which sentence is correct?

> The link you provided me is not correct, it is a link for xyz.

or this:

> The link you provided me is not correct; it is a link for xyz.

Comment: A coma is a long sleep.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it ok to combine two independent clauses into just one sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-ok-to-combine-two-independent-clauses-into-just-one-sentence)

Comment: The first one is not strictly correct but would be OK to most native English readers in an informal context (e.g. online chat or brief email).

Answer (score -1):

Your second sentence is correct, as is. However, to be correct, your first sentence needs a semicolon, not a comma.

You could, by the way, punctuate the sentence by using neither a comma nor a semicolon:

> The link you provided me is not correct but is a link for xyz.

As for what is correct grammatically, the thinking is if the two parts of the sentence (the part before and the part after the punctuation mark) can stand alone as sentences, then you can either make the punctuation mark a period or a semicolon, but not a comma.

A similar rule applies when adding an "interrupting word" to a sentence, as in

> He was smart, however, he lacked common sense.

That sentence could be made into two sentences or one:

> He was smart. However, he lacked common sense.

Or,

> He was smart; however, he lacked common sense.

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: @RamPillai: Indeed it is. I guess I forgot to mention that. Thanks for the reminder. Don

Comment: (1) This has been answered before several times. (2) Some famous authors have been happy enough to use comma splices. (3) Previous answers contained linked and attributed references.