# why are run-on sentences bad?

Tags: run-on-sentence

I have had questions on other boards edited with the reason "remove run on sentence"

but why are they bad I went to one page and the example was

> I have a dog his name is George.

The suggested solution was

> I have a dog. His name is George.

well I was taught that was wrong as you can't use his in a sentence alone, as a sentence is a standalone construct and we have no idea who "his" is (I have been roundly told my teacher was wrong).

another solution was

> I have a dog, and his name is George.

This appears to be a rule without reason, so please what is the reason?

---

I have read the suggested [duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348) ,which has been closed, it is about comma-splice with only a passing nod to run on sentences.

Comment: The rule about not using "his" in a sentence alone seems something you've made up or misunderstood, or someone else has made up and told you. Do you have any source for this rule? It's certainly not a generally accepted rule.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it ok to combine two independent clauses into just one sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-ok-to-combine-two-independent-clauses-into-just-one-sentence) Contains 'Comma splices are considered acceptable by some in passages of spoken (or interior) dialogue and are sometimes used deliberately to emulate spoken language more closely.'.

Comment: @StuartF my only reference is my secondary school teacher. We were taught so little grammar the little we were taught stuck.

Comment: I've _got_ to quote from the duplicate: "Take this sentence, for example: 'It's not a comet, it's a meteor.' According to Wallraff, 'punctuating this sentence with a semicolon would be like using a C-clamp to hold a sandwich together.' "

Comment: This is not an actual rule. For example, the second paragraph of Dickens' *The Mystery of Edwin Drood* opens "Shaking from head to foot, the man whose scattered consciousness has thus fantastically pieced itself together, at length rises, supports his trembling frame upon his arms, and looks around.  **He** is in the meanest and closest of small rooms." (My emphasis.)

Comment: @PeterShor I think that Dickens quote neatly demonstrates the difference between effective writing and clear communication, and how something can be one but not the other.

Comment: You can also, in theory, use a colon or an em-dash in formal prose. With fiction or poetry, you can be more "inventive" with your grammar. Still, a run-on sentence looks awkward to most native speakers

Comment: As to run-on sentences, as others have pointed out by now, they're not bad per se. (Just like nothing really is.) It's a question of style, an arbitrary social construct. (Just like all of writing really.) At this point in time, for this particular language, we happen to agree that this style here is good and that style there is bad. In other languages and/or at other points in time you might find the opposite to be true. Indeed, you might even find yourself having to write *everything* as a single run-on sentence with no punctuation or spaces whatsoever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In spoken language we use shorter or longer pauses to break up what we are saying into chunks that allow the listener to follow along comfortably. If you say  *I have a dog his name is George*  as one string of words without a pause, you give the listener little time to process each separate thought.

In written language the pauses are represented by punctuation, but they serve the same purpose. And rightly or wrongly, writers who fail to punctuate consecutive independent clauses, as in the dog example, may distract their readers and not be taken seriously. In any case,  taking care with punctuation demonstrates courtesy to the reader.

As to what you were taught about not using a possessive pronoun such as *his* in a standalone sentence, this may be true if you say out of the blue *His name is George*. But in normal conversation the context will make it clear who the *his* is referring to (in grammatical terms, its *antecedent*).

To conclude, it is certainly advisable to avoid writing two or more consecutive independent clauses with no punctuation. You can do this in three ways:

- By making the second clause into a new sentence
- By separating the two clauses with a semicolon
- By inserting a conjunction between the clauses

The term for two consecutive independent clauses separated by a comma (a fourth possible option) is *comma splice*. Comma splices are generally also considered run-ons and hence to be avoided. There are however circumstances in which a comma splice is not only acceptable but may also be stylistically the best choice.

Comment: Adding a parallel to "time to process each separate thought": If I wanted a breakfast of coffee, fruit, and pastry, I would hardly want them mashed into one bowl (the run-on sentence). The separation creates order.