# Is there any word for the upper inner part of a sock?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I was about to answer a question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) thread, and I wanted to refer to the inner upper part of a sock. Something like this:

> Put a small label inside the inner upper part of your socks.

But this seems very vague. Is there any single word or a good phrase for it?

This will make it clear:

[image: this part of the sock]

Comment: I can't really make out which part you are referring to based on the provided image.

Comment: @coleopterist the part where exactly the arrow is,which is little thick

Comment: Sometimes when I read those single-word requests I think English that has already half a million or even a million words would need five million words if there were a single word for all those requested here on this forum. A single word for the upper inner part of a sock - really such a word is missing and we need it really urgently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thicker (often elasticated) part of the sock is called the **cuff** of the sock. [Knitting socks](http://knitting.about.com/od/knittingglossary/g/sock-cuff.htm)

If that's too specialised, then you could simply call it the *open end*.

Comment: Hmm..so we can refer to it as: inner part of the cuff?

Comment: @joeyrohan, Or simply *the inner cuff.*

Comment: Or *inside the cuff* or *inside the open end*.

Answer (score -1):

Call it the [inside](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/inside?q=inside) [rim](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rim). That's plain English.

**inside** *adjective* [attributive] situated on or in, or derived from, the inside: *an inside pocket*
**rim** *noun* the upper or outer edge of an object, typically something circular or approximately circular: *a china egg cup with a gold rim*

Comment: +1,this is more understandable

Comment: When talking about socks, I believe [_cuff_](http://www.buybuybaby.com/1/1/1694-be-basic-turn-cuff-socks-ivory-12-24-months-mfrid-8701.html) is a better word to use than [_rim_](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cuff+of+the+sock%2Crim+of+the+sock&year_start=1970&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) – but maybe there's a regional difference I'm unaware of.

Comment: I have to agree, if you spoke to me about "the rim of a sock", I'm not at all sure I'd figure out that you meant the cuff.

Comment: I agree, a rim is something hard like a china egg cup, a cuff is specifically the edge of soft clothing, usually sleeves.

Comment: @Mynamite What tells you rim is something hard? (*a thick rim of suds*) Apart from a china egg cup, anything can have a rim. Cuff is the default term. However, note the answer from Andrew Leach where he thoughtfully qualifies it with *If that's too specialised* -- same logic holds in my avoiding that word.

Comment: @Kris I've had a think about this, and I'm not even sure what a thick rim of suds is, in fact I'm having a bit of [semantic satiation](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46306/whats-the-term-for-when-a-word-is-said-so-many-times-it-sounds-weird/46309#46309) about it! If it means the suds collecting round the edge of a bath then I guess I would say the hardness of the bath holds the suds in place - take the bath away and the suds dissipate. But that might be a bit pedantic.

Answer (score -1):

It's called the welt or the inside welt in this case.

Comment: Do you have any evidence, or reference to support your answer, just to be double sure :)

Comment: A "welt" is generally a seam, resulting in a "swollen" area (which is how this usage derives).  Sock makers generally try to avoid welts.