# What does "duly" mean in the phrase "duly noted"?

Tags: meaning, adverbs

The phrase "duly noted" is very common, but I have never used the word "duly" outside of this context.

What is the meaning of the word "duly", and what does it add to the word "noted"?

I would also like to know if there are other uses of "duly", and if it can be used on its own.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am becoming [semantically satiated](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6170/10041) with the word *duly*.

Comment: Duly duly duly duly.  Did that help?

Comment: @Daniel, The term <semantically satiated> doesn't mean what you think it does...

Comment: This might help: https://grammarist.com/usage/duly-noted/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*[Duly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/duly)* is the adverbial form of the adjective *[due](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/due)*.  It means either *properly* or *punctually*, and can be replaced by either word felicitously.  So *[duly noted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/duly+noted)* means *correctly or appropriately recorded*.

*Duly noted* encompasses only a tiny fraction of the usages of the word: this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=duly,duly%20noted&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) should be sufficient to illustrate:

[image]

*Duly* is as independent as it could wish.

Comment: Well that makes good sense! "Duly = due + ly".  Thanks!  Now I can stop making up answers to my wife.

Comment: "So *duly noted* means that the note fit the circumstances"? I would say that by far the most common context is as a "mock-formal" way of saying, "Yeah, I got that, thanks", often with a sarcastic or vaguely annoyed tone. As pointed out [in this discussion.](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=324578)

Comment: "Duly noted encompasses only a tiny fraction of the usages of the word" This surprises me, as I can't recall ever hearing it used any other way. To be honest, I took it as a set phrase.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel _The ceremony duly began at midnight._ _I used the tent and was duly impressed._

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks for jogging my memory :) It still doesn't exactly seem like those usages are the overwhelming majority, though.

Answer (score 1):

Contract terms and compensation are relative to this issues scope, size and workload. Increase to size and content shall be duly reflected in compensation.