# Minutes from a meeting

Tags: meaning

In this sentence:

> Thanks, John; that's duly noted.

what other word can you put instead of *duly noted*

Comment: Though not a direct answer, this link should give you an insight into duly noted. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47411/what-does-duly-mean-in-the-phrase-duly-noted

Answer (score 1):

It depends a little bit on the situation. *Duly noted* can mean a couple different things. From [Ask.com](http://www.ask.com/question/meaning-of-duly-noted):

> The phrase *duly noted* means that information has been received. The information will be given its due thought and consideration. It can also mean message taken and recorded.

If someone is correcting you, and you want to acknowledge that you understand the problem, you could say:

> Thanks, John; that's **duly noted**.

or:

> Thanks, John; **point well taken**.

As TFD says, this idiom means:

> **point is well taken** someone's idea or opinion is accepted and appreciated

Then again, if you're using *duly noted* to mean that you have jotted down an item from the meeting, and that you're now ready for the discussion to resume, you could simply say:

> Thanks, John; **got it**.

In the context of a speaker scribbling down something in a pad of paper, or entering it into a tablet, the phrase *got it* would mean, roughly, "I'm done writing now; let's continue the conversation."