# What is the word for this effect: things are not normally noticed until those things come in to the news and people fear/are looking for them

Tags: word-choice, terminology

For instance. I've never really paid attention to white vans, but when the DC sniper was at large and they stated that he's probably shooting from a white van, white vans seemed to appear out of no where and be around every corner!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [priming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_%28psychology%29), or attentional priming.  It is a well-studied phenomenon of attentional shift.

Interestingly, priming work both ways. That is, a sensory stimulus (like the white van) can in some cases cause you to increase your attention to similar (white van-like) stimuli, or it can cause you to ignore similar stimuli, depending on how the initial stimulus is experienced.

You heightened your detection of white van-like stimuli because you were told that they were a threat.  Likewise, you may have covertly suppressed your detection of red sedan-like stimuli containing nubile shapes in order to sharpen your alertness for white van-like stimuli, because the red objects could cause a potentially lethal distraction.

Priming is also used for some kinds of jokes.  Jokes with pun punchlines rely on perceptual priming where the listener is led to form a cognitive concept about a word and then has the meaning shifted for humorous effect.

I believe that priming is the culprit for [semantic satiety](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-the-feeling-you-get-after-looking-at-a-word-for-to) as well.

Comment: thank you for this; I had this exact question myself just the other day and I'm delighted to learn the proper term. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a variant of Confirmation Bias.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on this is refereshingly complete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias