# Can I use the noun "tenure" to refer to the length of time someone has worked for a company?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, business-language

I am in the situation where I would like to be able to concisely refer to the length of time an employee has been with the company. Can I use the word *tenure* in this case?

For example:

> The median tenure at this company is less than two years.

The dictionary definitions I've read of the word *tenure* are a bit too vague to tell me whether it can be used this way.

If it cannot, is there another term that would serve well in the given example?

Comment: There's an existing question [Term for how long employees stay within a company](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216742/term-for-how-long-employees-stay-within-a-company). *Tenure* is the answer there; although it might be ambiguous in some contexts (in education where tenure has a different definition).

Comment: There's also an ambiguity between time at the company and time in current position (e.g. if someone has been promoted). But that's maybe not significant.

Comment: Thanks @StuartF, for some reason I didn't find that when looking for existing questions!