# What preposition should be in the blank? “Follow-up notes ___ (to/on/of) the quiz booklet”

Tags: prepositions

The question is clear in the title. Also, if it matters, I’m using this as a title to my notes, obviously. I’m currently going with my guts and have written “to.” Please provide examples/counter-examples to back your answer. Thank you.

Edit: From comments below it seems like “on” is probably wrong in the context. “Notes on a Scandal” is alright but the “notes” I’m referring to are not “about the booklet” but rather have been taken out of the booklet with modifications. So, “Follow-up notes **on** the quiz booklet” feels wrong. But no one is sure yet. Also notice the article “the”. Hopefully, this clarifies the context.

Comment: I would expect to see 'notes on...'. When I googled the phrase I found a lot about the film 'Notes on a Scandal' and a few mentions of books called 'Notes on X'.

Comment: But unlike “a scandal”, these notes are not “about” the booklet rather they’ve been taken right out of the quiz booklet and modified, along with some added material. Should “on” be still appropriate?

Comment: @Foon Please [add that information](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/449676/edit) **to the question itself**. It's important and should not be buried in comments here. You might also add an example of such a note, just to be absolutely clear in what you are asking about.

Comment: I feel like it's the mix of "follow-up" and "notes" that's messing things up here. By itself, I say "follow-up" would be "to", and "notes" would be "on". For the combo, "on" still kinda works as "notes" is the head there, but really I'd just say "for". Follow-up notes for the booklet. I dunno. The more I think about it, the more I suffer from [semantic satiation](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/6174/300).

Comment: @RegDwigнt You seem to be on the right track. Only if there was a solid reasoning as to why “for” may be correct.

Comment: If they’ve been taken out of the booklet, then I’d probably say, “follow-up notes ***from*** the booklet”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully grasp what you are after here, but try these two suggestions as possibilities, to the extent that I have understood.

1). It strikes me that you might be talking about something written after the the quiz booklet, but closely related to its content.  If so, then quite a common term used by academic writers (as well as letter writers) is *postscript*.  It is derived from the Latin *post scripture* (= *after  written*).  It is falling out of general use now:  because of the computer, we can just insert extra bits into an email wherever we like.  So its acronym *PS* is gradually disappearing.  But *postscript* would work.  *To* would be the preposition to use.

1) The other word sometimes, especially if what you have written involves your ‘further thoughts’ or ‘further ideas’ might be *Footnote* or *Footnotes*.  Again, the preposition would be ***to***.

Comment: You understood the situation correctly and the suggestions seem convincing. “To” seems most appropriate here. But now you got me thinking about what if the two words “follow-up” and “notes” don’t go together? Anyway, I’ll mark this as the best answer.