# Inculcated With

Tags: grammaticality

Is this phrase incorrect or perhaps awkward?

> John was inculcated with certain ideas.

The phrase comes naturally to me. But I decided to check, and I can find no examples of it being used.

[Ngram viewer does return results but they're very minimal.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%3B%2Cc0)

The definition of *inculcate* at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inculcate) is:

> to teach and impress by frequent repetitions or admonitions

The synonyms at [Thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/inculcate) include:

> impart, indoctrinate, instill

This seems OK:

> John was indoctrinated with certain ideas.

Maybe this is one those kind of things where I've thought about it too much and now nothing sounds right.

Comment: This is one those kind of things where I've thought about it too much and now nothing sounds right.

Comment: It's a rarely used verb, and when used, normally has an active rather than a stative usage. So I'd expect "John was inculcated with certain ideas by these strange new friends."

Comment: Maybe not ***John***, and maybe not ***ideas***, but I found [*As a citizen of Athens, **Xenophon was inculcated with certain values***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+inculcated+with+certain%22) in Google Books. It's just *English*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see what you mean. I was going to go on "...inculcated with certain ideas in childhood..." Thank you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers ah, great find! thank you!

Comment: Yes; 'in childhood' is good 'padding' (as well as giving salient information), and now we obviously have the active (and perfective) usage.

Comment: As covered by one of our most upvoted questions ([*Is there a word or phrase for the feeling you get after looking at a word for too long?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-the-feeling-you-get-after-looking-at-a-word-for-to)), just about *any* word or expression can seem "weird" if you dwell on it too long. But a quick check through Google Books using a suitable search string can often bring you back down to earth.

Comment: [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=) gives lots. It seems in is more common than with but still many of each.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your usage of *inculcate* is slightly off.

In the active voice, somebody inculcates something in someone.

In the passive voice (as you've used), something is inculcated in someone [by somebody].

Here is an example:

> **Active**: *Cult leaders inculcated certain ideas in John.*
>
> **Passive**: *Certain ideas were inculcated in John [by cult leaders].*

To be sure, you can find your usage (active: inculcate someone with something; passive: be inculcated [by someone] with something) employed regularly:

> **Active**: ? *Cult leaders inculcated John with certain ideas.*
>
> **Passive**: ? *John was inculcated [by cult leaders] with certain ideas.*

But that usage hasn't really "hit the books" yet—that is, that's not how dictionaries recognize *inculcate*'s usage.

Here is the [OED](https://oed.com/)'s definition (login required):

> **inculcate,** *v.* **1.** *transitive.* To endeavour to force (a thing) into or impress (it) on the mind of another by emphatic
>   admonition, or by persistent repetition; to urge on the mind, esp. as
>   a principle, an opinion, or a matter of belief; to teach forcibly. 
>   Const. *upon*, *on*; †formerly *in*, *into*, *unto*, *to*.

This is from [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/inculcate):

> **to cause someone to have particular beliefs or values by repeating them frequently**:
>
> *The goal is to inculcate in students a tolerance for people of
>   other religions and races.*
>
> ---
>
> **to fix beliefs or ideas in someone's mind, especially by repeating them often**:
>
> *Our coach has worked hard to inculcate a team spirit in/into the
>   players.*

Modern lexicographer Bryan Garner [says in Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA504&dq=words%20that%20are%20misused%20%22inculcate%22&pg=PA504#v=onepage&q=words%20that%20are%20misused%20%22inculcate%22&f=false):

> *Inculcate* is sometimes misused for *indoctrinate*. Although these are both transitive verbs (i.e. they take direct objects), the nature
>   of the objects is different. One *inculcates* values into people; and
>   one *indoctrinates* people with certain values . . . H.W. Fowler noted
>   this aberration and called it "a curious mistake" . . . No longer is
>   it curious, but it is still a mistake.

Of course you needn't obey the style and usage "authorities," and it's quite often better to ignore them in spoken, informal English. But they *will* come sniffing around your papers.

Comment: Some of the OED's definitions have not been changed for decades. For *inculcate*, their most recent citation in the online version is 1874. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/synonym/inculcate) (a more up-to-date Oxford dictionary) gives in their thesaurus: *he tries to inculcate students with a sense of the beauty and joy of the subject*. The OP's usage is perfectly fine if you're not trying to speak early 20th century (or earlier) English.

Comment: @PeterShor: Lexico/Oxford is a descriptive lexicon focusing on how people currently use the language. That's great. As I noted, the OP's usage is regularly employed these days. But in formal writing, one will sooner or later run up against a traditionalist.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly the kind of possibility I had in mind when I set out. So, if I understand, my usage is fine colloquially but it would be better to rephrase it to say "certain ideas were inculcated in John from childhood," yes?

Comment: @dev_willis: Damned if I know what passes for fine or better around here. As an editor, I would go with the traditional usage of *inculcate* — up until that usage sounded less natural than any common usage. But we're nowhere near that point.

Comment: Judging from [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+with+the+idea&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%20the%20idea%3B%2Cc0), *inculcated with* has been in relatively widespread use since the early 20th century. You can't possibly avoid all the grammatical innovations that have occurred in the last hundred years so as to avoid traditionalists. And as far as I can see, nobody is actively objecting to this one.

Comment: @PeterShor comparing [*inculcated with* to simply *inculcated*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+with+the+idea%2C+inculcated&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%20the%20idea%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinculcated%3B%2Cc0) would seem to indicate that the latter is far more common than the former and I wondered if there might be a good reason for that. I'm glad to know that, whatever the reason, it's not blatantly wrong. Still, it's great if I can rephrase slightly to be more correct without sounding unnatural.

Comment: Try this ngram: [inculcated with ideas,inculcated ideas](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+with+ideas%2Cinculcated+ideas&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%20ideas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20ideas%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Ah, that does make some difference. It's interesting the difference between between including and [omitting "ideas"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inculcated+with%2Cinculcated&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinculcated%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinculcated%3B%2Cc0) in the phrase.

Comment: *Inculcated* by itself will also include every instance of *inculcated with*.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an additional source at [Garner's Modern English Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=2xv4CwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PA504&dq=words%20that%20are%20misused%20%22inculcate%22&pg=PA504#v=onepage&q=words%20that%20are%20misused%20%22inculcate%22&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that works.
"Females were so inculcated with the belief that such clothing was proper, ..." "Playing With the Boys: Why Separate is Not Equal in Sports" By Eileen McDonagh, Laura Pappano.

"... they were frequently presented as “savages and pagans” who had to be “christianized” and inculcated with the morals and values of “civilized” culture" "Sisters of the Academy: Emergent Black Women Scholars in Higher Education" by Reitumetse Obakeng Mabokela, Anna Lucille