# Is "be-gruntled" a word?

Tags: british-english, speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When does a word become a ‘word’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15099/when-does-a-word-become-a-word)

Someone in work asked about the welfare of my girlfriend, to which I replied "She's fine, a little be-gruntled but fine."  People knew what I meant, although on reflection perhaps I should have said *disgruntled*?  I'm just wondering why I said it this way, was I improperly abbreviating *to be disgruntled"?

Comment: Maybe, it is a word after all. *be-* + *(dis)gruntle* not *be-* + *gruntle* -- "Begruntle is a word that means to disconcert or to render something to be uneasy." http://uk.ask.com/what-is/what_is_the_definition_of_begruntle

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by asking whether  something is “a word”, or that it is not “a word”? You used it.  People knew what you meant. Thus, it is a word. Therefore, you must be asking some other question here, but what is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you meant she was in ill humour, then the word is *disgruntled*. If *be-gruntled* meant anything at all, it would mean that she had become gruntled. (Only writers of the stature of PG Wodehouse have much of a chance of having their neologisms widely adopted, as he did by creating *gruntled* as a back-formation from *disgruntled*.)