# How are words added to the Oxford Dictionary?

Tags: dictionaries

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an ‘official’ way to suggest a new word become part of the English language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25138/is-there-an-official-way-to-suggest-a-new-word-become-part-of-the-english-lang)
>   [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/what-are-the-criteria-to-adopt-new-words-into-english)
>   [Creating a new word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12580/creating-a-new-word)
>   [Regulatory bodies and authoritative dictionaries for English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/462/regulatory-bodies-and-authoritative-dictionaries-for-english)

I was reading an article on how the Oxford Dictionary was being updated, and wondered what criteria would make a word suitable for being in a dictionary. I used to assume that all words would be included in a dictionary of such reputation, but this is obviously not the case. So my question is, what makes a word applicable to be added in the Oxford Dictionary? Is there a process for choosing these new words? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome: did you do any research before asking this question? A single Google search for *adding words to oxford dictionary* yielded [a very pertinent link](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-do-you-decide-whether-a-new-word-should-be-included-in-an-oxford-dictionary) as the first result.

Comment: It's illogical "to assume that all words would be included in a dictionary of such reputation": New words are being created every day, and old words are dying every day. Only words that have been consistently used and are unlikely to disappear are invited to enter the lexicographer's clubhouses.

Comment: @BillFranke  It's not at all illogical if you start from the false but very common premise that the dictionary is authoritative and you can't use a word if it's not in the dictionary. How many posts do we get asking *I can't find this in the dictionary, is it a real word?*

Comment: You can make a start here: http://public.oed.com/about/

Comment: @StoneyB: I forgot that there were people who believed in that false premise. Thank you for reminding me. (8=O

Comment: I am going with the "duplicate" close reason as a courtesy to the OP, but really, this is off-topic and general reference.