# When does a neologism cease to be a neologism?

Tags: etymology, neologisms, language-change

What benchmarks or useful signs can be found to declassify neologisms? Obviously, inclusion in a dictionary is as likely as anything to declare a neologism a word but what happens just before that point?

Note that I am not asking how *long* it takes to convert a neologism. I am asking if there are there any good indications of neologisms about to phase into the lexicon.

The flip side is also interesting: When is it safe to say that a neologism is not likely to catch on without some drastic intervention? For instance, *kipple* is an interesting word with a distinct meaning but it seems so far outside of the cultural sphere that it seems safe to claim it will never become a recognized word.

I suspect that answers to the first part (what makes a neologism stick) are likely to answer the second part via absence. As in, if a certain thing is a good sign for a neologism, its absence is evidence *against* the neologism.

Comment: I hate to say it, but I'm not sure this isn't more of a linguistics question than an actual E&LU question.

Comment: @Robusto: I am fine with that. I still think it is an interesting question and I don't have anywhere else to ask it.

Comment: Actually, according to the faq this is perfectly on topic. Etymology is allowed and nothing explicitly says questions applicable to more than one language are not. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds dupish to me (not that I can promise the answers to these will satisfy you): [Creating a new word](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/12580/) ◊ [What are the criteria to adopt new words into English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11455/) ◊ [When does a word become a 'word'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/15099/) ◊ [When does a mistake become standard usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/9314/) ◊ [Descriptivism and widespread misspelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/3723/) ◊ [If I invent a word, what language is it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1990/)

Comment: @Reg: Eh... those questions and answers are _close_... but the answers here aren't doing much for me either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neologisms can be divided in three categories/phases:

> 1. **Unstables**: Those that belong to this category are the newest ones, as in being just introduced, or that are used by few.
> 2. **Spread**: As the name says, they are spread enough, so they are used by a wide number of people, but are not accepted as "normal" words yet.
> 3. **Stables**: Those who get accepted by the public audience and start to be used like other words become stable.

Anyway, although we can say that **when a word goes inside the Dictionaries, it is not a neologism anymore**, if it's being used so commonly and widely, it will be considered a normal word like others, and this is what counts.

Sometimes, even when experts or linguists don't agree on some neologism, for various reasons, what really matters is the **common usage** and the acceptance by the public audience, as you could also see from the three categories/phases I wrote above.

If the event/situation the neologism describes cease to exist, the word will stop being used and therefore disappear. This is to answer to your second question.

Answer (score 7):

As a rule of thumb, if it appears in a general interest broadcast or publication without being accompanied by a definition, it's probably not a neologism anymore.

However, this doesn't mean that a word accompanied by a definition *is* necessarily a neologism; it may simply be obscure or unfamiliar to the target audience.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I would just say that for me, a *neologism* tends to imply the new word (or its usage in a new context) is somewhat quirky. So nearly a quarter of a century after its first appearance I still think of **bonkbuster** as a neologism. Whereas **waterboarding** just seems like just a regular word, even if what it refers to is arguably irregular.

Comment: Companies may be stratified in a similar manner. The Economist will say "Publicis, a french advertising giant" for the second tier. No elaboration needed for "Apple." First tier terms belong in Scrabble and Bananagrams (a Scrabble derivative).

Answer (score 2):

One of my linguistics professors was fond of saying that by the time you'd heard a particular usage often enough for it to annoy you, it was too late—it'd already become entrenched.  I'd say that's as good a definition as any:  a word ceases to be a neologism when people start complaining about it.

Comment: Some words annoyed me after I first heard them...

Comment: Some people continue to be annoyed by the same words from childhood to old age. Not necessarily neologisms either - often good old Anglo Saxon four-letter words!