# Is metathesis correct?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology

Pronouncing *asterisk* as *asterix* /æstərɪks/ is called metathesis.

Some common examples of this phenomenon that I have heard are *ask* -> *aks* and *introduce* -> *interduce* /ɪntərˈdjuːs/.

So this phenomenon has a fancy name. But is it correct to say *asterisk* as *asterix*? How does one decide whether it's metathesis or just a mispronounced word?

Comment: Related: [Pronunciation and spelling of “asterisk”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10189/pronunciation-and-spelling-of-asterisk), [Why is “ask” sometimes pronounced “aks”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12074/why-is-ask-sometimes-pronounced-aks)

Comment: My understanding is that the phenomenon is *always* referred to as metathesis, whether it's a one-off error or the accepted norm. *Thirteen* is metathesis, so is *aks*, so is *pasketti*. So the question basically boils down to [When does a mistake become standard usage?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9314/when-does-a-mistake-become-standard-usage)

Comment: @RegDwight is right on the money.  Words often change over time, and one way they can change is through metathesis.  After some time, if enough people (or perhaps more importantly, the *right* people) pronounce a word a new way, the new pronunciation can eventually be adopted as standard. But there is no guarantee of standardization for a given pronunciation of a given word.

Comment: Usage changes over time, but "asterix" and "axe" are both likely to get you funny looks round these parts.

See also "religious tenants" - drives me mad, that one.

Comment: Random fact: in Greek there is also *metathesis quantitatis*, "change of length". (*Quantitas* is a Latin word, but we often use Latin words to describe Greek.) With two successive vowels, it is possible that only their *lengths* are swapped. *Polis* ("city, city-state"), genitive **pole(y)-os*, would regularly be **polē-os*. But the long *e* becomes short, and the short genitive ending *-os* is lengthened in compensation, to become *poleōs*. M.q. usually occurs where a PIE semi-vowel has disappeared, either yod (y) or wau (w).

Comment: nucular; prostrate (in speaking of the prostate gland).

Comment: It has a special name because it's common; and it's common because it's a normal result of the way the mechanics of pronunciation works. In other words, swapping consonants is an easy thing to do (try pronouncing _Unique New York_ three times fast and see what you wind up doing) and therefore quite often generates new words in new contexts. So it's always metathesis, and it may or may not be a mispronunciation -- that depends on who's judging.

Comment: 1) "Scrimmage" is  a metathetic transformation of "skirmish," and "dirt is a metathetic transformation of "drit. " 2) My father taught me,"Mary upon the ice did frisk. How foolish of her, her *. " 3) Here's a verse from the American folk song, Revolutionary Tea," Oh mother, oh mother," the daughter replied, I shan't do this thing that you ax. I'm willing to pay a fair price for the tea, but never no thr' penny tax."

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that as of today, the pronunciation *asterix* is definitely incorrect.

But given there are plenty of dialectal contexts where it's okay to pronounce  *ask* as *ax*, things may feasibly change.

Comment: You have to capitalize the "A" in _Asterix_; it's a proper name, after all. But it's pronounced correctly ending in /ks/.