# Question about singular/plural with present perfect

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Is the following sentence correct?

"Two thirds of land has already been sold."

Is it correct as it has the singular have verb "has" or it shoulb be rewritten with the plural verb "have"?

Comment: You're using *land* as a mass noun, so the singular *has* is correct here.

Comment: Also, you probably want to say "the land" (assuming that the reader already knows which land is being referred to). Otherwise, the implication is that you're referring to 2/3 of all land. And "two-thirds" should be hyphenated.

Comment: @Lawrence: Technically, the head of the subject is *thirds*, which is plural, so the verb should also be plural.

Comment: @Andy I got this phrase from a test we had at school and I used the plural because I thought that "two thirds" was plaral since it says two thirds not a third so I can't change the sentence to something different

Comment: Even though I used plural the teacher marked as wrong answer.

Comment: @Cerberus In *"About seven tenths of air is Nitrogen."* with *air* as a mass noun, I don't think the plural works. With "Three quarters of my students wear glasses.", it does because "my students" is a count noun.

Comment: @AndySchweig: good suggestion to add "the", but I disagree about the hyphenation. If "thirds" was being used adjectivally, e.g. a **two-thirds** share, then the hypenation would be correct. But in this case "thirds" is acting as a noun, so the adjective "two" stands on its own. Think of the difference between "a third of the share" and "a one-third share". And I agree with Cerberus that thirds is the plural subject noun.

Comment: It seems like we have a good debate!

Comment: I think "two-thirds" is a written out fraction, which should always be hyphenated. If a "third" is a recognized unit of land in this context, then it should be written "two thirds".

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/should-you-use-a-plural-verb-if-you-refer-to-a-fraction

Comment: Good question, stimulating comments and helpful reference, which leads me to retract my agreement with @Cerberus about the plural verb, and further leads me to bring it all together in an answer :-)

Comment: @Lawrence: My statement was mainly intended to indicate that this construction isn't quite so simple as it might appear, and that *land* isn't even the head noun. But I said "technically" in order to hedge my statement...sometimes the ordinary rules of agreement are trumped by something else. Cf. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, I was going to add that I agree with your statement, then started tossing up between *thirds* and *land* before deciding my linguistics wasn't up to par. Good point about complexity - I wondered about it, too. The ELL post Phil Sweet linked has good observations in the answers, but I feel there should be more *why* underlying the *what*. [Proximity agreement](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/54719/142322) may be involved (also referenced [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/69693/142322), as well as your own link), though that's normally considered a source of error.

Comment: @Lawrence: It is normally considered a source of error, but at some point an extremely common error stops being! It is always very complicated to decide when. Another linguistic phenomenon to consider is [notational agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis), if you take as the subject *two thirds of the land* as a whole without analysing it and assign a notion of singularity to it.

Comment: @Cerberus We're in fierce agreement. :)

Comment: @Lawrence: Absolutely not!!

Comment: @Cerberus Ok, I can't speak for you, but for my part, I had considered "taking *two thirds of the land* as a whole". This is certainly a valid way to resolve the issue regarding grammatical number.

Comment: @Lawrence: I was joking! We are indeed in agreement. I just felt an unstoppable need to fiercely disagree with fierce agreement.

Comment: When a @Cerberus is disagreeable, one must stand one's ground :) . Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the question and related comments, two separate "fraction" issues have emerged.

> 1. Should the verb be plural because it refers to a fraction?

Generally speaking - though there are exceptions - the fraction takes the same plurality as the thing it modifies; see [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5269/should-you-use-a-plural-verb-if-you-refer-to-a-fraction) for a good explanation. In the specific context of the present question, "the land" is singular therefore it's appropriate to use the singular verb "has".

> 2. Should the fraction be hyphenated?

This depends on how the fraction is being used. In situations where the fraction is a noun, there should be no hyphen, whereas if the fraction is being used as an adjective to describe something else, it should be hyphenated; see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72614/why-does-one-half-have-no-hyphen-but-two-thirds-does/72622#72622) for an explanation. For example:

- "Two thirds of the land" [the "thirds" here is a plural noun, with
  "two" being the adjective that modifies it];
- "Two-thirds share of the land" ["thirds" is now acting as an
  adjective modifying the noun "share", and "two" is acting like an
  adverb modifying "thirds"].

So in the present question, it's correct to write the fraction without the hyphen.