# Is this salutation correct, "Hi, <name>-"

Tags: salutations

I have seen this salutation written to me in an email, " Hi, -" Is this correct grammar  ?

Comment: What do you suspect is incorrect about it? It looks normal to me, although there is usually punctuation after the name.

Comment: I take a stab in the dark and close this as a dupe as a courtesy, but really it is not clear at all what you are asking, and in its current form this question is plain off-topic. Please clearly specify what you think the problem is, why you think so, and what alternatives you have considered. You might look up [the meaning of *grammar*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300) first. A single word cannot be grammatically wrong. And if this question really is about the comma as I'm guessing, then it's not about grammar, either, it's about punctuation.

Comment: I agree that my question could have been worded better. However I don't believe that it is "plain off-topic"  The question even in it's vague form still refers to the use of a salutation in the english language. Thank you for those that answered the question, even it's vague form.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of opening an e-mail, in all but the most formal of contexts, is:

> Hi [name],

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct, but it may not be appropriate in terms of formality. 
What is the person's relationship to you? It is most likely that person's attempt to close the interpersonal distance between you and he or she by using a less formal address.