# Following a statement with a question

Tags: grammar, questions

> Person1: "I'm feeling quite rough today."
>   Person2: "That sucks - what's the matter?"

Is Person2 using correct punctuation, or should there be a comma to separate the statement and the question?

Comment: I would use a period (full stop.)  Both are complete sentences.  "That sucks.  What's the matter?"

Comment: I might use the dash: It's stronger than a comma but weaker than a full stop, indicating a change of direction in the sentence while still carrying the overall sentiment.

Comment: Of course he is using correct [*grammar*](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300). Commas are *punctuation*. (Or do you actually have any beef with the grammar? Then you must clarify what it is.) And no, using a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) there makes no sense whatsoever. Not in English, not in any language. If anything, you were aiming for a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don't know why I put "grammar", thanks for pointing it  out. Yes, you are right in thinking I was aiming for a dash.

Answer (score 2):

“That sucks” and “what's the matter?” are [independent clauses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause). Joining them with a comma is a [comma splice,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice) which is generally considered a style error in English. [Dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), [colons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29), [semicolons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semicolon), and [full stops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop) (periods) are all acceptable punctuation for separating independent clauses:

> That sucks. What's the matter?
>   That sucks; what's the matter?
>   That sucks: what's the matter?
>   That sucks—what's the matter?

The different punctuation marks indicate subtle differences of intonation and meaning. The full stop indicates two separate, complete thoughts, whereas the semicolon is a weaker break indicating two related thoughts. A colon introduces the second clause as an expansion or explanation of the first. A dash may represent a more abrupt break, or it may simply be used as a visually distinct alternative to a semicolon or colon. Any of them may be appropriate for the example sentence, depending on the exact shade of meaning intended.

Answer (score 1):

Person 2 is speaking two sentences. There should be a period.

Person1: I'm feeling quite rough today.
Person2: That sucks. What's the matter?

"That sucks." is a complete sentence.  "What's the matter?" is a complete sentence.

Comment: A full stop isn't the only way to separate two independent clauses. Colons, semicolons, and dashes can all serve well in that role, especially when the two clauses together form a complete thought.