# How should we put a website address into a sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence, writing-style

Is the following a right way to put a website address in a sentence?

```
You can visit the website http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask for English     
grammar problems.
```

Comment: website *at* or *@*.

Answer (score 1):

[The Chicago Manual of Style](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/search.epl?q=urls) would indicate that this is perfectly acceptable usage of a URL in a sentence.

You need a login to read the full details, but [here are some publicly-accessible Q&As on using URLs in sentences that may come in useful](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/URLs.html).

Answer (score 1):

That is a perfectly valid way, but the sentence as a whole is unnecessarily unwieldy. It doesn't read well at all.

First off, you don't need to specify it is a website, that is perfectly clear already. Likewise, the "you can" is worthless ballast. And nobody uses `http://` anymore. Waste of space.

Next, I do not visit that URL *for* problems. You're saying I will *get* problems if I go there. No, thanks. What you want to say instead is that I should visit to make the problems I already *have* go away.

Also, it's not problems. That's too generic. An overused and overloaded word. As the URL itself indicates, I go there to *ask questions*. So say just that. Be clear and specific.

Lastly, it's not only questions about grammar. I can also ask about punctuation, orthography, pronunciation, etymology, morphology, formality, politeness, dialects, idiolects, slang, and whatnot. *Grammar* is not a catch-all term for "something and anything with language". Grammar is only one [very specific aspect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300) of language.

So:

> Visit [english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you have a question about English.