# "Can you hear me okay?"

Tags: grammar

Is this construction correct? I hear it a lot in spoken conversations, but would this construction survive gramatical scrutiny? If yes, can then "okay" act as an adverb?

Comment: None of the dictionaries you checked listed it as an adverb?

Comment: If you "hear it a lot in spoken conversation", then as a matter of fact it [already *has* survived grammatical scrutiny](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300). (As long as you're looking at native speakers, of course.)

Comment: Okay is satisfactory as an adverb.

Comment: It's definitely informal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can you hear me okay?" - Here, the word "okay" means one of the following:

fine, well, all right, fine, well enough, satisfactorily, etc.

Yes, it acts as an *adverb* here, since it qualifies "hear".

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english-thesaurus/OK?q=okay&searchDictCode=american_english