# When is a English dialect considered to be non-grammatical/have non-grammatical phrasing?

Tags: grammar, phrases, dialects, non-standard

So the question is when a dialect of English is considered *non-grammatical*. I am aware that it can be considered *non-standard*, however some phrases can be *to an extent* not to be considered non-grammatical. So where the cases in which it is actually considred *non-grammatical*. Thanks.

Comment: Every single dialect of English is grammatical within itself. [Read this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26283/300) to understand what grammar is.

Comment: @RegDwigнt So technically a dialect can never be _non-grammatical_ if it follows all its own rules (no matter how far apart it is from being _grammatical_)?

Comment: @Strikers Yes. Grammaticalness is with reference to a particular variety. A phrase can be grammatical in one dialect and not grammatical in another. A dialect can be socially acceptable or not within a given social circumstance.

Comment: @Mitch Okay thanks, and also to note, it is then considered _non-standard_.